# Reverse all the values in column from highest values to lowest values and vice versa in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
   column  column1
0      23       12
1      12       23
2      14       21
3      17       20
4      21       14
5      18       18
6      20       17
```

I want the highest value of the **column** to be replaced with the lowest value, 2nd highest with 2nd lowest like this for all values till the lowest value replaced with the highest value of the column as shown above in **Expected Output**. How to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace sorted values with reverse sorted values:

```
>>> df['column2'] = df.column.replace(df.column.sort_values().values,
                                      df.column.sort_values(ascending=False))
>>> df
   column  column2
0      23       12
1      12       23
2      14       21
3      17       20
4      21       14
5      18       18
6      20       17
```

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary of `zip` by sorted values with same values with swapped order and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
a = df['column'].sort_values()
df['column1'] = df['column'].map(dict(zip(a, a[::-1])))
print (df)
   column  column1
0      23       12
1      12       23
2      14       21
3      17       20
4      21       14
5      18       18
6      20       17
```